# If $(\Omega, d)$ is complete and $A$ is closed in $\Omega$, then $A$ with respect to the induced metric is complete (proof)

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(\Omega, d)$ be a metric space, and let $A \subseteq \Omega$. I would like to prove that, if $(\Omega, d)$ is complete and $A$ is closed in $\Omega$, then $A$ with respect to the induced metric is complete.

Below I write my attempt. It seems right to me... What do you think about it?

**My attempt.**

Since $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$ with respect to the induced metric, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \geq N$, $d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon$.

Since $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the complete metric space $(\Omega, d)$, it converges to a point $x \in \Omega$ by the definition of completeness.

Since $A$ is closed in $\Omega$, it contains all its limit points. Since $x$ is the limit of the Cauchy sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\Omega$, $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Therefore, there exists a sequence $\left(y_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = x$.

By the triangle inequality, for all $n \geq N$:
$$
   d(x_n, y_n) \leq d(x_n, x) + d(x, y_n) < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
$$

This inequality shows that the sequence $\left(y_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$ (which is also in $A$). This implies that $A$ is complete with respect to the induced metric.

**My new attempt.**

Proof. If $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the induced metric, then it is a Cauchy sequence in $\Omega$. By assumption, it has a limit $x \in \Omega$. Since $A \subseteq \Omega$ is closed, it follows that $x \in A$, from which $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $A$.

Comment: Why do you need a new sequence $(y_n)$? $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ which converges to $x$, and necessary $x\in A$, because $A$ is closed. So this proves $(x_n)$ has a limit in $A$.

Comment: I hypothesized the existence of another sequence and then I proved with the triangle inequality that they are practically the same thing. I understand from your comment that it is a pointless step.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Yeah, now it's correct.

Comment: @Mark Thank you!